# Sermepa payment system and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, payment

I'm trying to set up an online payment system using Serpema which is an spanish system. 
I'm using online confirmation: after payment is accepted, the system sends me a POST with confirmation data and here is where I have the problem because CI rejects that post coming from an external server due (I think) to csrf protection.

I post no code as what I need to know is some way to get that post. CI says "the action you have requested is not allowed" and when I see the payment system log it has been returned a 500 error.

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was CSRF Protection. You can disable it for the controller->function that gets the post in Hooks